# Pagemethod doesnt work from asmx file rather aspx any suggesion?

Tags: vb.net, asmx, webmethod

I am using simple json method for calling webmethod
but it works with aspx file ie url:

```
'myclass.aspx/myfunction'
```

but it doesnt work if I put same function in an asmx file and change url to asmx.

Is there anything else have to be done to enable asmx service ?

asmx with vb code: // this works

```
<%@ WebService Language="VB" Class="WebService" %>

Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
Public Class WebService
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()> _
    Public Function abc(ByVal args As String) As String
               Return returnValue
    End Function

End Class
```

asmx with codebehind file

```
<%@ WebService Language="VB"  CodeBehind="default.vb" Class="default" %> //this doesnt work
```

code behind file

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class mintnow_default
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()> _
    Public Function abc(ByVal args As String) As String
               Return returnValue
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to decorate your service with the `<ScriptService>` attribute if you want to be able to invoke it with a JSON request:

```
' you need to add the ScriptService attribute here
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService>
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
Public Class WebService1
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function MyFunction() As String
       Return "Hello World"
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: i added that line <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _

Comment: @user1167053, how exactly does your method signature look like and how exactly are you calling it from javascript?

Comment: is it ok if i put code in same file or it matters for security concern?

Comment: Is this a web site project (File->New Web Site)? That would explain the problem.

Comment: Web sites are a pain when it comes to anything interesting like web services. Don't use them if you can avoid them.

Comment: i think you are right for now i will go with single file if i find the exact cause i will put here thanks bydway :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to remove the `Shared` keyword from the service methods.

Comment: hmm what exavtly static keyword?? i dont get you

Comment: auto generated asmx says to uncomment <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _ this line i did but its nt working

Comment: Your Page Methods are, for instance, `public static int SomeMethod(int param)`. Get rid of `static`.

Comment: its not statis its public shared function

Comment: So you're using VB.NET. Get rid of `Shared`.

Comment: i tried that ,still not working it works perfect within aspx codebehind file

Comment: Can you show a small amount of the code that's "not working"? Also, can you say what you mean by "not working"?

Comment: code is same as darin mentioned above just in VB there is no error when i say not working means if i put webmethod function in aspx code file or in asmx file json method passes parameter values and webmethod returns right answer but if i put same function in codebhind file same code no change just add a link in asmx file at top codebehind="this.vb" then function doesnt return value on html page it keeps showing loader.gif thats timeout function for executing webmethod

Comment: The class name is "mintnow_default", not "default".

Comment: thats typo... actula class is mintnwo_default

Comment: What is the definition of `returnValue`? I don't see it getting set.

Comment: hmm it can be anything even return "hello word" is not returning